# How to redirect a web repository to a local folder in a ROS package?

Tags: ros, roomba, rate, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!!!

I'm newbie in this. I'm trying to use the turtlebot packages in a Roomba 600 but I can't. I've found that the default rate is 57600 and I need to change it to 115200. I've saw in the folder "create_driver" that it is at `/opt/ros/indigo/share/create_driver` the "package.xml" file and this file uses the roomba driver of a github repository, this is the code:

```
<package>
  <name>create_driver</name>
  <version>2.3.0</version>
  <description>
    Driver for iRobot Create and Roomba
    
    This is a generic driver for iRobot Create that currently holds
    implementations for Turtlebot and Roomba. Port
    of pyrobot.py by Damon Kohler.  It is currently labeled as
    turtlebot_driver pending review by the entire create community
    before using the name create_driver.
  
    For ROS bindings, please see turtlebot_node.
  </description>
  <maintainer email="turtlebot@osrfoundation.org">OSRF</maintainer>
  <license>MIT</license>
  <url type="website">http://ros.org/wiki/create_driver</url>
  <url type="repository">https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_create</url>
  <url type="bugtracker">https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_create/issues</url>
  <author email="damonkohler@google.com">Daemon Kohler</author>
  <author email="kwc@kwc.org">Ken Conley</author>
  <author email="mwise@willowgarage.com">Melonee Wise</author>

  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>

  <export>
```

In that repository uses a baud rate of 57600 and my robot works with 115200, I've download the package of this repository and I've change it the baud rate but I don't know how to use it instead of the web repository, that I imagine is this line code :   `<url type="repository">https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_create</url>`

Thanks in advance!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247395/how-to-redirect-a-web-repository-to-a-local-folder-in-a-ros-package?/) by [Diana_Elyza](https://answers.ros.org/users/27895/diana_elyza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2016-11-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Abdul Mannan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25557/abdul-mannan/) on 2016-11-06**:
I have some questions. Have you created workspace and initiated it? Do you know how to clone the package getting it from online? Maybe, I could help you getting the answer of these questions.

**Comment by [Diana_Elyza](https://answers.ros.org/users/27895/diana_elyza/) on 2016-11-06**:
Thanks to show my question Dr, with respect to his questions, I have a workspace and I know how to clone a package, but I cloned the "turtlebot_create" package in this directory `/opt/ros/indigo/share/` because I imagine that this package is a complement of the "turtlebot_bringup" package.

**Comment by [Diana_Elyza](https://answers.ros.org/users/27895/diana_elyza/) on 2016-11-06**:
I've followed this tutorial [http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_bringup/Tutorials/indigo/TurtleBot%20Bringup] to execute this package with the respective configurations of the roomba base, but I have not connection, I think that it is by the baud rate.

**Comment by [Diana_Elyza](https://answers.ros.org/users/27895/diana_elyza/) on 2016-11-06**:
By that reason I found that the roomba driver is execute it online or I think so, and this driver is configured in 57600 bauds. For this reason I wonder how to execute this driver of locally way so I can make the change of the baud rate.
Thanks by your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to create a workspace to put your code inside and be able to use it there.

This topic is covered in the beginner tutorials: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials I'd recommend working through all of those as it will cover this topic as well as a bunch of other ones which will help you be able to debug your system.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Diana_Elyza](https://answers.ros.org/users/27895/diana_elyza/) on 2016-11-06**:
Thank you very much by your answer. Do I need to put all the turtlebot package in my workspace??? Because I followed this tutorial [link text](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_bringup/Tutorials/indigo/TurtleBot%20Bringup) and I did the settings for a roomba base.

**Comment by [Diana_Elyza](https://answers.ros.org/users/27895/diana_elyza/) on 2016-11-06**:
I've found that there are many complements of the turtlebot package, like the "turtlebot_create" package that contains the roomba driver. By that reason I do not how to redirect the driver of these package to the "turtlebot_bringup".
Thanks by your attention.